# Selenium on mac gives elementNotVisibleException

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Here is the test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import time

def test(urlx):

    br = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')
    start_time = time.time()
    br.get(url)
    restaurant_url_sel = u'.restaurants a'
    ta_restaurant_button = br.find_element_by_css_selector(restaurant_url_sel)

    print str(ta_restaurant_button.text)

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("---|||||||||||||||||||||||||| %s seconds |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||---" % elapsed_time)
    print br.page_source


url = 'http://www.tripadvisor.com/Tourism-g150812-Playa_del_Carmen_Yucatan_Peninsula-Vacations.html'
test(url)
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapeall_destination.py", line 20, in <module>
get_restaurants(url)
  File "/Users/pablocastelo/Desktop/tripadvisor/get_restaurants.py", line 67, in get_restaurants
ta_restaurant_button.click()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 65, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 385, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated",
```

The output as you can see (I only included the relevant part of the page source) does in fact show the element is there, what is going on?  The test has zero problems running on Ubuntu.

```
MacbookAir:~ hotr$ python ~/desktop/test2.py

---|||||||||||||||||||||||||| 11.2492170334 seconds |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||---

<li class="restaurants twoLines">
<a href="/Restaurants-g150812-Playa_del_Carmen_Yucatan_Peninsula.html" data-trk="restaurants_nav" onmousedown="ta.common.header.addClearParam(this);"> <img src="/img2/x.gif" class="typeIcon sprite-restaurants_icon" alt="" width="42" height="41">
<span class="typeName">Restaurants</span> <span class="typeQty">(745)</span>
<span class="contentCount">46,865 Reviews</span>
<img src="/img2/x.gif" class="sprite-nav_arrow" width="8" height="11">
</a> </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html) for an element *[to be visible](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located)*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def test(urlx):
    br = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')
    br.get(urlx)

    ta_restaurant_button = WebDriverWait(br, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.restaurants a'))
    )


url = 'http://www.tripadvisor.com/Tourism-g150812-Playa_del_Carmen_Yucatan_Peninsula-Vacations.html'
test(url)
```

Comment: Didn't work on the Mac.  I get the exception msg:    File "/Users/hotr/Desktop/tripadvisor/get_restaurants.py", line 72, in get_restaurants
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, restaurant_url_sel))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza ok, but what if you try chrome or firefox instead? Just to test.

Comment: Yes it does work with Chromedriver. But it's preferable to use phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1124, 850) # set browser size.
browser.get("http\:example.com") # Load page
```

The solution is we need to set a fake browser size before doing browser.get("").
see the issue in [github](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11637)